# Is there a way to count the number of upvotes and downvotes I performed today?

Tags: discussion, support

Is there a way to show the number of upvotes and downvotes one have casted on today, or a given day?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see your votes on profile page

1. Go to Votes section in your profile
2. Filter by Upvote/Downvote and you'll see the list of all the votes till now.

As you can see this will just give you complete list, the votes performed today have to be manually counted with the help of date column.

---

One other way is to track your next badge if you haven't already got it.

There are two badges for daily votes

1. Suffrage
2. Vox Populi

By tracking one of these badges, you can get the count of total votes used today.

[image: Suffrage Vote Count]

[image: Vox Populi]

Note that, this will give the count of votes used only on current day, for other day use the above method of manual counting.

Comment: I understood this, but I'd like a counter, to know how many votes I have remained to be able to vote.

Comment: Ah, indeed, tracking the Suffrange badge sounds a good idea!

Answer (score 2):

There is no convenient counter of this kind. The profile page displays the total of today's upvotes and downvotes, but the page is aggressively cached, which usually makes the count out of date for active voters. There is a feature request [Reliable count of votes that I've cast today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239601).

I wrote a bookmarklet [Votes cast today](http://normalhuman.github.io/stackmarklets/#votes) which scrapes the /votes tab of the profile and displays all counts [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTy7M.png).